# Converting Packed COBOL

Tags: c#, sql, cobol

I am trying to update a COBOL packed field via a SQL query in a C# application. Currently, the COBOL packed field is being stored in a character column (char(50)) in a  MS SQL database.

COBOL Data Type = 4 Byte binary number (“PIC S9(9) COMP”):

I can use the following statement to extract the data. I am not sure on how to reverse this processes for data updates.

CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING({Column Name},{Start},4) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS BIGINT) AS {Alias_Name}

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Brennan Mann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer coming late. But anyway ... here goes:
If it's indeed PIC S9(9) COMP and not COMP-3 then it's not a 'sinister' COBOL packed field but a simple 4 byte integer!

Comment: Do you know how a COMP-3 is defined?

Comment: @Brennan Mann: COMP-3 = PACKED DECIMAL. Good overview can be found here: http://www.simotime.com/datapk01.htm

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs this... This was the solution with C#

```
 public string ConvertToFourByteBinaryNumber(Int32 value)
    {
        byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

        Array.Reverse(intBytes); // IsLittleEndian

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(intBytes);
    }

    public string ConvertToEightByteBinaryNumber(long value)
    {
        byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

        Array.Reverse(intBytes); // IsLittleEndian

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(intBytes);
    }
```